# Double if condition in Spry Region

Tags: spry

```
<div spry:region="ds1" spry:repeatchildren="ds1">
  <b spry:if=" '{title}'!='' ">
    <!-- this is the first if --> 
    <a href="#"  spry:if=" '{author}'!='' ">{author}
      <!-- this is the second if -->
    </a>
  </b>
</div>
```

I wonder if there is any method as simple as

```
if(x==y && i>j)
```

in

```
<b>spry</b>
```

region.
I can't find any information in spry docs  (labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax inside the `spry:if` attribute is Javascript, so you can use `&&`:

```
<b spry:if="'{title}' != '' && '{author}' != ''">
<!-- ... -->
</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

also you can call a function instead

```
spry:if="myFunc();"
```

and in your function return Boolean value as result

```
function myfunc()
{
//do somethings ;
if(...)
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I do like this

```
<div spry:region="ds1" spry:repeatchildren="ds1">
    <b spry:if=" '{ds1::title}'!='' && '{ds1::author}'!=''">
        <a href="#">{author}</a>
    </b>
</div>
```